# How to enable spell check in CryptPad?

Tags: firefox, spell-check

Is there an easy way to enable/customize spell check in [CryptPad](https://cryptpad.fr/)?

I ask this because I have not found any spell check option in the control navigation bar but I see that it's somehow supported:

[image: CryptPad screenshot with spell check]

Moreover, if I do right-click on the error it does nothing.

Thank you! I'm using Mozilla Firefox at the moment but the situation does not change with Chromium or other browser webs.

Comment: I see that I cannot create the CryptPad tag since I have not enough privileges.

Answer (score 0):

### How to enable spell check in CryptPad

If you do not see any red text-correction in CryptPad, follow this:

1. Click on your user icon on the top-right corner of the page and select *Settings*.
2. You may see a warning message asking to "enable popups". Say *Yes* (since it's not spam but just your settings page)
3. On the Settings page, click on *Rich Text* (from the left sidebar)

NOTE: This page can be found also visiting an URL like `https://example.com/settings/#pad`

Now click on this checkbox called "*Enable spell check in rich text pads*".

Done! Now reload your pad.

### How to customize spell check in CryptPad

Hold the `CTRL` key on your keyboard (or the `Meta` key, or `Cmd` key in other environments) and then do a right-click on a word.

If you do that, the native spell check system in your browser-web should appear:

[image]

You can for example:

- add a word to your dictionary
- change language
- deactivate or re-activate spell check

Note: if your language is not available, probably you have not the right dictionary installed on your computer. Search stuff like "how to install dictionary in Mozilla Firefox" or Chromium or whatever is your browser-web.